# setTheme function not working on resume

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to use setTheme function which basically set theme based on some DB value but the problem is once I have updated DB with theme to be set,I need to finish() the activity for theme settings to be implemented. code being  -

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settingsDBAdapter = new SettingsDBAdapter(this);
        settingsDBAdapter.open();

        setSettingsTheme();  <<------THIS LINE WILL SET THEME
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_task_manager);

        quickAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuickAddButtonId);
        quickAddTaskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.QuickAddEditTextId);

        mDBHelper = new TasksDBAdapter(this); 
        mDBHelper.open();


        fillData();
        //code to create long press on any list item and calls onCreateContextMenu method
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();


    }

public void setSettingsTheme(){
        String currentTheme = settingsDBAdapter.fetchThemeSettings("theme");
        Log.i(TAG,"settingsDBAdapter + currentTheme-->" + settingsDBAdapter + currentTheme);
        //setTheme(R.style.HoloTheme);
        if(currentTheme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("holo")){
            Log.i(TAG, "in holo<<<<<<<<");
            setTheme(R.style.HoloTheme);
        }else if(currentTheme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("hololight")){
            Log.i(TAG, "in hololight<<<<<<<");
            setTheme(R.style.HoloLightTheme);
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "iin else<<<<<<<");
            setTheme(R.style.HoloTheme);
        }
    }
```

I have also tried calling setSettingsTheme() function after overriding onResume() function still of no use.`Log.i` present in setSettingsTheme() function gives proper value always.
Can anyone please help me in my understanding. Thanks in advance,Kaushik

Comment: are you calling setContentView() after each call to setTheme()?

Comment: i m just calling finish() after user exits application and so when user restarts the app setCOntentView() is called.Is there anyway to unet it sumhow so that user dont need to restart the app.?

Comment: So I ran into a similar problem creating watch faces for my Moto360. For better or worse I used the following: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int, boolean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [`ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29) says:

> Set the base theme for this context. Note that this should be called
>   before any views are instantiated in the `Context` (for example before
>   calling `setContentView(View)` or `inflate(int, ViewGroup)`).

The `Theme` attributes are read in the `View`s constructors, so after changing the theme you'll want to recreate the UI. You can call `finish()` and then `startActivity(getIntent())` in your Activity to restart it, or have to code a way to rebuild each and every View object.

Comment: I tried the same by calling finish() if user clicks on back button on activity.But is this the only way to implement.?

Comment: Yes, it is. The `View` constructor is the only place where the `Theme` object is queried. There's no way no notify the `View` objects that the theme has been reset. The only chance is when you use custom views: in this case you can provide optional callbacks to allow *hot swapping themes*. However Android doesn't provide such a framework

Comment: Also setTheme() should be before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); on android 2.3 i had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, hat tip to Raffaele for pointing me in the right direction on this.

Also, I know this is an old post, so if there is now a better way to do this please let me know.

Anyway...

I ran into a similar issue trying to create a watch face for my Moto360. You can't change the theme instance that is referenced by the View hierarchy, but you *can* force that instance to take on the attributes of the theme you want to switch to. If you get a reference to your theme and call `Resource.Theme.applyStyle(int,boolean)`, the attributes of the target theme get applied to the theme referenced by your View. After that a call to invalidate the View will update the UI with the new styling.

For example: (Somewhere in your activity ...)

```
 Resources.Theme myTheme = SomeActivity.this.getTheme();
 View myThemedView = SomeActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.myRootView);
 myTheme.applyStyle(R.style.MyOtherTheme,true);
 myThemedView.invalidate();
 // Above, "true" clobbers existing styles, "false" preserves them
 // and attempts to add in any new attributes.
```

Again, I did this on a watch face Service on a Moto360 without incident. I have not tried this on an Activity yet.

[Resources.Theme.applyStyle(int,boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int,%20boolean))

You can see my code [here (BatmanWatchFaceService.java)](https://github.com/wileymab/moto360watchfacestudy/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wileymab/watchfacetwo/BatmanWatchFaceService.java).